# How to add an individual feild in the view

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, sql-server

i am trying to make a view in MS SQL having join of two table and an individual field.
i have done the joining part but now i want to add a new field in this view which is not in any of the table which is joined. 
so anybody have any idea how i can create this new field in the view.

Comment: What will this additional field contain? Some static value or will it be some calculated value, based on values of some other fields?

Comment: this additional field is a bit values to check the status of a particular record..

Comment: Do you mean that this bit values checks status of each record based on records from join of two tables?

Comment: create view Slots as 
SELECT     Event.EventId, Event.eventName, examCenter.centerId, examCenter.centerName, slotTime.slotTimeId, slotTime.FromTime, slotTime.ToTime, slotTime.Dated, 
                      examCenter.noOfSeats,**(active bit) as Active**
FROM         examCenter INNER JOIN
                      Event ON examCenter.eventId = Event.EventId INNER JOIN
                      slotTime ON Event.EventId = slotTime.eventId

Comment: I want to add a feild **ACTIVE** of type **bit** into this View...

Comment: Ok so what's the condition that decides a row is active or inactive?Is it some value in a column or you want all records to be active by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want a default value for all your rows in the `ACTIVE` field, try this

```
CREATE VIEW Slots AS 
SELECT Event.EventId, 
Event.eventName, 
examCenter.centerId, 
examCenter.centerName, 
slotTime.slotTimeId, 
slotTime.FromTime, 
slotTime.ToTime, 
slotTime.Dated, 
examCenter.noOfSeats,
CAST(1 AS bit) AS Active 
FROM examCenter 
INNER JOIN Event 
ON examCenter.eventId = Event.EventId 
INNER JOIN slotTime ON Event.EventId = slotTime.eventId
```

If the value for the `ACTIVE` field depends on some condition, say

```
slottime.Dated => getdate()
```

then, you will need to replace

```
CAST(1 AS bit) AS Active
```

in the above code, with

```
CAST(CASE WHEN slottime.Dated => getdate() THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS bit) AS ACTIVE
```

Comment: I want to add a feild ACTIVE of type bit into this View... this ACTIVE is a new field.. it is not in any table..

Comment: Answer modified. The new field ACTIVE of BIT data type does not exist in either table and is created at run time

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly name each field if you need, aliasing them with AS as required. For example:

```
SELECT si.field1 as si_field1,
       si.field2 as si_field2,
       ind_data.field1 as ind_data_field1
  FROM sites_indexed as si
  LEFT JOIN individual_data as ind_data 
         ON si.id = ind_data.site_id
```

And then you can reference the aliased names in your result set.

Comment: I am not asking about the alias name in joins... my question is quite diffrent sir..